# #define issue if its called from within a if() block

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have function: `foo()`

I want to write a `#define` to put 'infront' of `foo()` (a shim I guess) to add debug to the front of `foo()`.
So the `#define` should look this this:

```
   #define foo(dev) {                         \
      printk("%s: get %lx\n", (dev)->name);   \
      foo_orig(dev);                          \
   }
```

And then I rename `foo()` to `foo_orig()`.

This works OK if `foo()` function is called in 'isolation' like this:

```
   foo(dev);
```

BUT, if its called within an `if()` then it is a compile problem...

```
   if (something() && foo(dev)) {
     ..
```

Have I explained the issue?  and Is there a solution for this?

The problem is that I really need the shim as define because I need the code to live in the calling function rather than `foo()`.
[The reason for this is because I need to dump out the EIP the the calling function for debug reasons (i.e. I need to know who is calling `foo()`].

Comment: Why not make a function instead of a macro that calls printk and then returns the value of foo_orig?

Comment: Not sure which compiler you use but you should be able to expand the preprocessor directives and look at the code the compiler sees (and dislikes) after the expansion

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the comma operator should work:

```
#define foo(dev) (printk("%s: get %lx\n", (dev)->name), foo_orig(dev))
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm compiling fine if the left expression of comma is `void`. Perhaps your thinking of function arguments?

Comment: Nice to know - I never tried it with `void` in the first position, assuming that it was going to fail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using GCC, then this should help:

```
#define foo(dev) ({                           \
      printk("%s: get %lx\n", (dev)->name);   \
      foo_orig(dev);                          \
   })
```

The key point is parentheses around curly braces.

[GCC: Statements and Declarations in Expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how `#define` works.

At the preprocessing stage, the compiler will replace any occurrence of `foo` with the defined text. So, your code will look like this:

```
  // call to foo() -> valid
  printk("%s: get %lx\n", (dev)->name);
  foo_orig(dev);    

  // within a parenthesis - invalid 
  if (something() && printk("%s: get %lx\n", (dev)->name);
          foo_orig(dev);) {
```

One solution would be to use a real function for debug, like this

```
foo_dbg(type *dev) {
   printk("%s: get %lx\n", (dev)->name);
   return foo_orig(dev);
}
#ifdef DEBUG
   #define foo(dev) foo_dbg(dev)
#else
   #define foo(dev) foo_orig(dev)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

#define is like doing a search and replace. So your 'if' statement becomes the following at compile time:

```
if (something() && { print(....); foo_orig(dev);}) {
}
```

That should explain the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the comma operator:

```
#define foo(dev) (printk(blah, blah), foo_orig(dev))
```

With C99 you can use an inline function

```
static inline rtype foo (type *dev) { printk(blah, blah); return foo_orig(dev); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps replace the semi-colons `;` in your `#define` with commas `,`, and remove the braces/brackets `{}`.

Or, in your `if` statement, replace `foo(dev)` with `(foo)(dev)`.

Comment: and what is about the return value?

Comment: @Thomas Berger: The return value of the comma operator is the RHS.

Comment: @ThomasBerger: I have to think a bit more. Maybe the the braces should be replaced by parenthesis.

Comment: @ThomasBerger without parenthesis it will be improperly evaluated in the if statement shown.

Answer (score -1):

> The reason for this is b/c i need to dump out the EIP the the calling function for debug reasons (i.e. I need to know who is calling foo()

Well, you could just write some assembly to look up the return address on the stack; but actually, most compilers have already a builtin to address this need; see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) for GCC (for Clang it's the same), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64ez38eh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for VC++ (and on the Intel compiler it's the same).

Just write your shim inside the real `foo` and use `_ReturnAddress()` / `__builtin_return_address(0)` to get the return address of the function (i.e. one instruction after the `call` instruction that started the function).

Comment: The problem is not getting the address ...  the `printk` should work fine.